# Why python read tiff images slower when using random generator to retrieve the image paths

Tags: python, numpy, random, tiff

I am trying to write a python program to randomly read some tiff images from a large sample tiff images. Interestingly, I found that python tends to read the tiff images (with floating point values) much slower if we use random generator to generate indices and obtain the list of the image paths, as compared to use hard code random indices to obtain the image paths and read the tiff images.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

def read_in_seq(image_filenames, indices):
    return [ plt.imread(image_filenames[index]) for index in indices ]

image_filenames = []

for index in range(15000):
    image_filenames.append("/tmp/%05d" % index + ".tiff")

# This is generated from numpy.random.choice(15000, 100) but hard coded the values here
indices=[
  3885,   901,  6233,  7234, 10195,  2204,   469,  2906, 12114, 13515, 12977, 5201,
  8829, 11537,  5400,  9633, 10744, 12991,  2593,  3046,  5103,  1901,  8831, 12454,
  9779,  4714, 10839,  8702,  8537,  2136,  5095,  9006, 13293,  9933,  3584, 10818,
  8594, 11032,  3705,   435,  6679,  8349,  6930,  9741, 12933,  3231,  1849,  7871,
 11752,  8361,  3094,  2229, 14303,  2006,  5554,  1492, 14817, 12690, 10648, 14631,
  6401,  6181,  4401,  7222,  9881,  8381,  7603, 11374, 12702,  6881, 11868, 10967,
 14508, 12930,  3542,  1197,  8387, 11253,  1802, 14732,  7419, 11994,  6083,  8846,
  5370,  4276, 13953, 14409,  8197,  8956,  4717,  3262,  2314, 12527,  5394, 12495,
  6708,  9724,   740, 10416]

print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') + ": Normal input read started with size=" + str(len(indices)))
output = read_in_seq(image_filenames, indices) # takes 0.8 seconds
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') + ": Normal input read completed with size=" + str(len(output)))

indices = numpy.random.choice(15000, 100)
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') + ": Random input read started with size=" + str(len(indices)))
output = read_in_seq(image_filenames, indices) # takes ~3 seconds
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') + ": Random input read completed with size=" + str(len(output)))
```

Here is the output:

```
2018-01-10 15:30:46.170487: Normal input read started with size=100
2018-01-10 15:30:46.943557: Normal input read completed with size=100
2018-01-10 15:30:46.943718: Random input read started with size=100
2018-01-10 15:30:49.858074: Random input read completed with size=100
```

All 15000 tiff images are identical, ~3MB each. As you can see, normal input read with hard coded random indices for 100 tiff images out of 15000 tiff images only takes 0.8 seconds. However, it takes almost 3 seconds when we use the indices generated from the random generator (e.g. `numpy.random`).

On the other hand, if we modify the above code to read 100 png images out of 15000 images. The time to read the png images using the hard coded random generated indices is almost the same as the indices generated by `numpy.random` (about 4 seconds).

```
for index in range(15000):
    image_filenames.append("/tmp/%05d" % index + ".png")
----
2018-01-10 16:20:30.498341: Normal input read started with size=100
2018-01-10 16:20:34.020450: Normal input read completed with size=100
2018-01-10 16:20:34.020602: Random input read started with size=100
2018-01-10 16:20:38.692906: Random input read completed with size=100
```

Please note that the time measure to read the tiff images does not count the time taken by `numpy.random` (only count the time to read the image `read_in_seq`).

Let's assume we can only use single thread, please can someone explain why python read tiff images slower when using random generator to retrieve the image paths (as compared to hard coded random indices to retrieve the image paths)? e.g. is it related to CPU floating point support, hard-drive seek, OS design or something else?

Comment: You didn't mention the time it took to read PNGs in both cases. This could be simply the case that invoking the random number generator (RNG) dominates the run time when reading low-complexity formats (like TIF), but when reading more complex formats (like PNG), the RNG becomes negligible compared to the run time for decoding the images.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa Thank you for your reply. I have added the time it took to read PNGs. Please note that RNG is not counted towards the time measure of image read.

Comment: You are right! Just also note that `numpy.random.choice` will sample with replacement by default, which you might not want to do.

Comment: @sascha I have ran both tests many times and obtained similar results. Is it possible to clear the cache if you think this is related to cache issue?

Comment: Not it's more complex than that. To minimize cache-effects: do a ramdisk-based benchmark (where everything is read from memory). But in your case it might also be related to those tiffs (if pngs behave different). Modify your benchmark to read the same images (in different order). 3MB does not mean much in terms of decoding-performance (e.g. no compression vs. compression and 4x times the pixels). For futher analysis, create a histogram of read-times over all reads to recognize this! (assuming you meant the *same* in regards to size; not content).

Comment: @sascha  I am sorry that I have no knowledge about ramdisk-based benchmark. Is it something that I can modify the python code to do that? It would be great if you can shed some light on it ;)

Comment: Google it. It's an OS-thing, like caching (which makes it hard to analyze from within python only).

Comment: @sascha I did some google with the keyword "ramdisk-based benchmark" but does not get any direction. Please can you kindly suggest what to search?

Comment: @sascha By the way I remembered I have copied everything to a new PC that I haven't ran the code and obtained similar results. So I don't suppose it is related to caching?

Comment: I think you misunderstand caching (and caching is broad; tons of different stuff can be meant; like prefetching and co.; HDD-blocksizes...). If you are not able to find out what ramdisks are, it's hard to help. Even your sub-optimal search-phrase will lead you to the idea. But to be honest: there are tons of tiny things to try (some already mentioned) and specififcs are missing + we can't do the same analysis. Your are somewhat on your own here.

Comment: the only thing I can see that is different is that in the first case `indices` is a list & in the second case `indices` is a `numpy` array. Not sure why this would make a difference, maybe something to do with the way numpy arrays are dereferenced?